# IIS7 doesn't display bound IP addresses

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-6, nic

So I have ten extra IPs bound to my network adapter.  When I go to add a binding usually IIS7 presents me with a list of IP addresses that are available, however I only have 127.0.0.1.  I can manually enter the IP address to bind host headers to the websites.  However I would still like IIS to function normally and present me with all of the IP adresses that are bound to the adapter.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out, I should just stop asking questions on here I seem to answer a lot of my own.  There was an entry in the hosts file that bound 127.0.0.1 to the hostname of the computer, removing this solved the IIS issue.